# Excel formula to C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, formula

Can someone convert this excel formula `=1-(POWER(10,LOG(0.8)/12))` to C#?

I've tried with this C# code, but the result is not the same:

```
1 - (Math.Pow(10, Math.Log(0.8) / 12))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Excel function LOG is base 10 by default. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/log-function-4e82f196-1ca9-4747-8fb0-6c4a3abb3280

The .NET Math.Log() function is base e by default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.log?view=netframework-4.7.2

You have to change `Math.Log(0.8)` to `Math.Log10(0.8)` like this.

```
1 - (Math.Pow(10, Math.Log10(0.8) / 12))
```